# Proving a homomorphism is surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group; let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$, with $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Let $HK= \{xy$|$x \in H$ and $y \in K \}$.

Prove that the function $f(k)=Hk$ is a homomorphism from $K$ *onto* $HK/H$, and its kernel is $H \cap K$.

---

So this follows from a few (already proven) important facts:

$$(1) \ H \cap K \ \text{is a normal subgroup of} \ K$$

$$(2) \ HK \ \text{is a subgroup of} \ G$$

$$(3) \ H \ \text{is a normal subgroup of} \ HK$$

$$(4) \ \text{Every member of the quotient group} \ HK/H \ \text{can be written in the form} \ HK \ \text{for some} \ k \in K.$$

---

Proving this is a homomorphism was simple:

Take any $a,b \in K$. Then $f(ab)=H(ab)=Hab=HaHb=f(a)f(b)$. So $f$ is a homomorphism from $H$ to $HK/H$.

---

Now for surjective: Take any $Hk \in HK/H$, we know this works from (4) above. Then there exists $g$ such that $g=Hk$.

Now I'm not sure if that is even correct. How do I go about showing $f$ is surjective? I have such a hard time with proving surjectivity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your f is  surjective because for every $Hhk \in HK/H $ we have that $$Hhk = Hk$$ and so $Hhk  = Hk = f(k)$